# integrate surface of disk in cylindrical coordinates and cancellation of radial component...

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: integration of disk in cylindrical coordinates]
I'm given this position vector in cylindrical coordinates:

$\vec{R} = -r\hat{r} + h\hat{z}$

So i find the magnitude and unit vector of this position vector:
$R = \sqrt{(-r)^2 + (h)^2}$

$\hat{R} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + h^2}} (-r\hat{r} + h\hat{z})$

Then, i'm suppose to use this position vector to integrate over the surface of a disk using this differential:

$d\vec{E} =  \frac{\rho_s~dA}{4\pi \epsilon_0 R^2} \hat{R}$

now integrating over the surface of a disk:

$\vec{E} = \int \limits_S \frac{\rho_s~}{4\pi \epsilon_0 (r^2+h^2)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + h^2}} (-r\hat{r} + h\hat{z})~dA$

$\vec{E} = \int \limits_S \frac{-\rho_s r\hat{r} + \rho_s h\hat{z}}{4\pi \epsilon_0 (r^2+h^2)^{3/2}} ~dA$

$\vec{E} = \int \limits_S \frac{-\rho_s~ r~\hat{r} }{4\pi \epsilon_0 (r^2+h^2)^{3/2}} ~dA + \int \limits_S \frac{\rho_s~ h~\hat{z}}{4\pi \epsilon_0 (r^2+h^2)^{3/2}} ~dA$

$\vec{E} = \frac{-\rho_s}{4\pi \epsilon_0 } \bigg(\int \limits_S \frac{r}{(r^2+h^2)^{3/2}} ~dA~\bigg)\hat{r}  + \frac{\rho_s}{4\pi \epsilon_0 }  \bigg( \int \limits_S \frac{h}{(r^2+h^2)^{3/2}} ~dA~ \bigg)\hat{z}$

in cylindrical coordinates the area differential is equal to: $dA = r~dr~d\theta$

$\vec{E} = \frac{-\rho_s}{4\pi \epsilon_0 } \bigg(\int \limits_0^{2\pi} \int \limits_0^h \frac{r^2}{(r^2+h^2)^{3/2}} ~dr~d\theta~\bigg)\hat{r}  + \frac{\rho_s~h}{4\pi \epsilon_0 }  \bigg(\int \limits_0^{2\pi} \int \limits_0^h \frac{r}{(r^2+h^2)^{3/2}} ~dr~d\theta~ \bigg)\hat{z}$

At this point I have the integrals setup and can evaluate them.... The integral of $\hat{z}$ term is easy enough...

But, Here's the part I don't get... Apparently, we can just know by inspection that the integral of $\hat{r}$ term is zero without performing the integral.  How does that part work?

Comment: By the way, you cannot in general pull the unit vectors like $\hat{r}$ out of the integral, because it changes from point to point; specifically, $\hat{r} = \cos \theta \hat{x} + \sin \theta \hat{y}$, so you can't pull it out of the $\theta$ integral (unlike $\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}$, which are the same at every point in space).

Answer (score 2):

Your integral for $r$ is incorrect for a subtle reason: you pulled the unit vector out of the integral like a constant, when in reality $\hat{r}$ is a function of $\theta$. The integral of $\sin\theta$ or $\cos\theta$ over $2\pi$ is $0$, so the $\hat{r}$ integral vanishes.

Comment: ok... interesting... so I need to shove the $\hat{r}$ back into the integral... but for the $\hat{z}$ its ok to pull it out of integral since its just like the cartesian $\hat{z}$

Comment: @pico that is correct

Answer (score 0):

$I = \int \limits^{2\pi}_0 \int^a_0 \frac{r^2}{(r^2+h^2)^{3/2}}~dr~\hat{r}~d\phi$

let $K = \int^a_0 \frac{r^2}{(r^2+h^2)^{3/2}}~dr$

we could find the exact value for K, but its value is not important...

$I = \int \limits^{2\pi}_0~K~\hat{r}~d\phi$

unit vector $\hat{r}$ is a function of $\phi$:

$\hat{r} = \cos \phi ~\hat{x} + \sin \phi ~\hat{y}$

$I = ~K\int \limits^{2\pi}_0(\cos \phi ~\hat{x} + \sin \phi ~\hat{y})~d\phi$

$I = ~K\int \limits^{2\pi}_0\cos \phi~ d\phi~\hat{x} + ~K\int \limits^{2\pi}_0\sin \phi ~d\phi~\hat{y}$

Integral over one cycle of sin or integral over one cycle of cos is zero.  Therefore,

$I = 0$